# Android xml layout messes up when ran on a device

Tags: java, android

In android studio when I see my app in the design view in XML it looks fine to me (just how I want it). But when I run my app on my device which is a Moto G the layout seems to just flop to one side. Why is this?

My Moto G device below (all the views and features flops to the side)

[image]

The design view in android studio. Everything looks good.

[image]

My XML code below

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:background="@drawable/backgroundpage"
    tools:context="xetron.appathon.orbis.landmarks">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:text="Landmarks"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#005491"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/landmarkName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#005491"
            android:text="UK"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lmkname1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#8FCE7B"
        android:text="Forbidden
 Kingdom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
 />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lmk1china"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:id="@+id/lmkimg1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lmkname2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#8FCE7B"
        android:text="Shanghai
   Tower"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lmk2china"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lmkimg1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:id="@+id/lmkimg2" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lmkname3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#8FCE7B"
        android:text="Great Wall
 Of China"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lmkname4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#8FCE7B"
        android:text="Temple Of
  Heaven"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
        />




    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lmk3china"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lmkimg1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:id="@+id/lmkimg3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lmk4china"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lmkimg2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/lmkimg4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a design with less fixed sizes (e.g. image-size 180dp), because this will never scale well on all screen-sizes. I find it never easy to build a well-scaling layout and you have to test it right away while building.

That said, you can create different layouts, for different screen sizes by appending the size to the xml-filename. This is, however, mainly used to define different layouts for the major screen-sizes: phone, tablet, landscape, portrait. It is not used to define a separate layout for difference in inches.

Answer (score 0):

You must avoid to use "hard" values in dimensions. Use "dip" instead. Also, use weights for elements positioning.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```